# Can you help me to solve an error in optim function in R?

Tags: r, optimization

I am new to R. I want to do some parameters estimation by using Maximum Likelihood Estimation.

Here is my attempt:

The data are

```
my_data = c(0.1,0.2,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,6,7,11,12,18,18,18,18,18,21,32,36,40,
          45,45,47,50,55,60,63,63,67,67,67,67,72,75,79,82,82,83,
          84,84,84,85,85,85,85,85,86,86)
```

and

```
lx <- function(p,x){
  l <- p[1]
  b <- p[2]
  a <- p[3]
  n <- length(x)
  lnL <- n*log(l)+n*log(b)+n*log(a)+(b-1)*sum(log(x))+(a-1)*sum(log(1+l*x^b))+n-sum(1+l*x^b)
  return(-lnL)
}
```

Note: l is λ, b is β, and a is α.

And here is the `optim` function

```
optim(p=c(1,1,1),fn = lx, method = "L-BFGS-B",
      lower = c(0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001),
      control = list(), hessian = FALSE, x = my_data)
```

After I run this code, I get an error message:

```
Error in optim(p = c(1, 1, 1), fn = lx, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(1e-04,  : 
  objective function in optim evaluates to length 50 not 1
```

What's wrong with my code? Can you help me to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a log-likelihood, use `MASS::fitdistr`.

```
#
# Power Generalized Weibull distribution
#
# x > 0, alpha, beta, lambda > 0
#
dpowergweibull <- function(x, alpha, beta, lambda){
  f1 <- lambda * beta * alpha
  f2 <- x^(beta - 1)
  f3 <- (1 + lambda * x^beta)^(alpha - 1)
  f4 <- exp(1 - (1 + lambda * x^beta)^alpha)
  f1 * f2 * f3 * f4
}
ppowergweibull <- function(q, alpha, beta, lambda){
  1 - exp(1 - (1 + lambda * q^beta)^alpha)
}

my_data <- c(0.1,0.2,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,6,7,11,12,18,18,18,18,18,21,32,36,40,
             45,45,47,50,55,60,63,63,67,67,67,67,72,75,79,82,82,83,
             84,84,84,85,85,85,85,85,86,86)

start_par <- list(alpha = 0.1, beta = 0.1, lambda = 0.1)
y1 <- MASS::fitdistr(my_data, dpowergweibull, start = start_par),
start_par2 <- list(shape = 1, rate = 1)
y2 <- MASS::fitdistr(my_data, "gamma", start = start_par2)

hist(my_data, freq = FALSE)
curve(dpowergweibull(x, y1$estimate[1], y1$estimate[2], y1$estimate[3]),
      from = 0.1, to = 90, col = "red", add = TRUE)
curve(dgamma(x, y2$estimate[1], y2$estimate[2]),
      from = 0.1, to = 90, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, after I plot the histogram and the pdf with the estimated parameters, it seems like the pdf doesn't fit the histogram. I don't understand why this happen.

Comment: @ccmatyn You didn't say you wanted to fit a distribution. What is the distribution? Both are important and should be in the question.

Comment: The distribution is Power Generalized Weibull Distribution. The pdf is lambda.beta.alpha. x^(beta-1).(1+lambda.x^beta)^(alpha-1).exp( 1-(1+lambda.x^beta)^alpha)